# I have a trouble in Payment gateway

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

im doing Android application online purchasing and payment gateway also using. According to EBS guideline i do all procedures. But  i  cant do successfull payment

> AndroidMainfest.xml

```
   <activity
        android:name=".PaymentSuccessActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_payment_success" >
         <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="@string/hostname"//hostname=EBS
                android:scheme="com.example.bazar" 
                />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

> bulid.gradle

```
    dependencies {
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile project(':EBS')
}
```

> in PaymentActivity.java

```
double totalamount=12.34;
HOST_NAME = getResources().getString(R.string.hostname); //HOST_NAME=EBS;
*
*
*
*
  custom_post_parameters = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> hashpostvalues = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashpostvalues.put("account_details", "saving");
    hashpostvalues.put("merchant_type", "gold");
    custom_post_parameters.add(hashpostvalues);

    PaymentRequest.getInstance()
            .setCustomPostValues(custom_post_parameters);
EBSPayment.getInstance().init(buyProduct, ACC_ID, SECRET_KEY,
          Config.Mode.ENV_LIVE, Config.Encryption.ALGORITHM_MD5, HOST_NAME);
```

in logcat i got message

```
POST DATA{ship_postal_code=678702, session_id=f49017766ab63ef612a4bd1b9d6e224e,
 mobile_type=android,
 card_expiry=1216,
 phone=9495638104, 
 merchant_type=gold,
 emi=, card_number=4*************12,
 ship_country=IND,
 ship_name=c,
 package=com.example.bazar://EBS?, 
 state=Kerala, account_details=saving, display_currency=, 
 city=palakkad, currency=INR, mode=LIVE, amount=12.34,
 description=Test Transaction,
 name=c, 
 page_id=, 
 ship_city=palakkad,
 ship_address=palakkad,palakkad, 
 account_id=1****8,
 card_cvv=123, 
 bank_code=,
 name_on_card=Test Transaction, 
 country=IND, 
 return_url=https://qa.secure.ebs.in/v3/response.php, 
 ship_phone=9495638104, card_expiry_cvv=0,
 email=sunjithc@gmail.com, address=palakkad,palakkad, postal_code=678702, payment_mode=1, store_card=1, reference_no=346, channel=2, ship_state=Kerala}
```

**screenshot of error message. sometimes invalidsecurehash message also showing** 
  [image: error message]

Comment: Have you created an app in ebs account ??